# Identify the manufacturer of these circuit boards?

Tags: pcb, identification, history

At a surplus sale, a friend picked up a *large* number of old circuit boards, probably 30-40 in all. Here's the box:

[image: Box of circuit boards]

All the boards seem to be made by the same manufacturer and probably come from the same device. Notable components include motors, dials, and op-amps (LM741CN).

Close-ups of some of the boards:

[image: Board with motors]

[image: Board with diodes]

and the back side of the motor board:

[image: Backside of board with motors]

The most notable and obvious feature of these boards is the logo:

[image: Logo]

This logo is on the back of every PCB, although I could not identify it with either reverse image search or by searching for the description.

Can anyone identify the manufacturer? Maybe narrow down what era of technology this is (probably 1970-1980 but that's a big range)? Or what this device might have been? It's to satisfy a burning curiosity :)

Comment: Determining the manufacturer and what devices they are is unlikely possible unless they're labelled. Date codes on the ICs visible to '76-'77. The last picture is probably a PCB maker's mark. Your curiosity is probably unsatisfiable unfortunately. Why would anyone buy a box of old boards of unknown origin?

Comment: My friend has a fascination with older technology, and likes to snap up these sorts of things and rework them into art projects. For example, he made a few lighting fixtures using these old circuit boards as lampshades.

Comment: maybe Fluke or Tektronix judging by the custom part numbers and vintage... note photo #2 shows a Motorola chip with a custom topmark starting with 551-  if you can figure out which manufacturer used 551- as prefix for Motorola manufactured components, that's a start. Maybe browse the online `boat anchor` manual repository?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: Heh, I would, except I am pretty curious about the parts too.

Comment: They're old, all right. The two ICs in the second pic have date codes of summer 1977.

Comment: Two adjustable inductors are labelled **D** and **C#**. Are there similar boards with other labels, say from **A** to **G**?. If not, I'm sorry but you don't have a full set... However at this point I would be looking for electronic organ manufacturers with **J** in the name, active in the mid-late 70's. Expect those boards to be master oscillators; others to be frequency dividers by 2,4,8 etc for the octaves, and possibly analog filtering and sound shaping...

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Spot on! Nice catch. I dug through and found another board with F and F# on it, so this is definitely a musical instrument. I've never heard of an electronic organ before today, but that certainly sounds about right. Thanks!

Comment: The only potential organ maker I can find is Johannus who have a Facebook page ... https://www.facebook.com/johannus.orgelbouw/timeline ... today their logo is quite different and they make both pipe and digital instruments, but a polite enquiry *might* trigger some memories ... or not.

Comment: Motor board ... see "Leslie effect".

Answer (score 6):

Those boards appear to be parts of an electronic organ. The image below is from an from an [eBay auction](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Kimball-Organ-Tone-Generator-Divider-Board-B-C-/131404833998) - described as a "Kimball Organ Tone Generator/ Divider Board B & C". It looks very similar to yours (same number and order of pins on the edge connector, similar coils with almost identical labels).

[image]

Comment: Interesting...Kimball was known as Jasper Corporation for a while (although they changed their name in 1974). I wonder if that logo might be J for Jasper...

Comment: beat me to it! http://www.kimball.com/kimball_history.aspx

Comment: Searching for "Jasper Electronics organ" produces a string of patents, some with circuit diagrams which might be useful, but no logo so far... There are serious electronic organ enthusiasts who may be able to help.

Comment: Strange, I have a ton of these boards as well! Picked them up from a scrapped electric organ at the local dump... I have the full assembly of the cards with the large coils on them, There are two notes per card, and they plug into a wire wrap backplane. The ferrite slugs in the coils are glued in place.